# CMake on Windows 10 doesn't generate executable

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017

So I have a tiny C++ project that I code on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm using CMake to coordinate relatively platform-independent build processes. I'm no master of CMake, but it worked up until recently, however now I cannot get the solution generated by CMake-gui to actually compile into an executable to run, despite my usage of add_executable. Here is my CMakeLists (there's a hideous mix of platform-specific stuff in there, however it appears that CMake simply ignores it):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project (TestProject)

include_directories(C:/include/CImg-2.2.2)

ADD_LIBRARY(LibsModule Game.cpp Game.h TestGame.cpp TestGame.h)

target_link_libraries(LibsModule -lpthread)
target_link_libraries(LibsModule -lm)
target_link_libraries(LibsModule -lX11)

add_executable(TestProject TestGame.h)

target_link_libraries(TestProject LibsModule)
```

This compiles and runs fine on Ubuntu using CLion, however on 64-bit Windows 10 using VS17 it fails upon trying to run the executable it expects to be generated because the executable doesn't exist in the build folder (but the .lib file noted is generated just fine).

I've seen some mention that a third party antivirus program could cause this, but I have no such thing installed.

Now I'm pretty new to CMake so if this file is completely off the mark I would really appreciate a clear explanation as to what I'm doing wrong, this code is made from a short study of basic CMake usage.

Comment: Why is the only source file a header file?

Comment: I heard that some generators for CMake do not like executable/library without any source file. Try to add at least empty `.c` file to your executable.